# How to use WordPress 3.5 media manager gallery tool for my own plugin

Tags: wordpress, media, wordpress-3.5

In the WordPress 3.5 media manager under the "Create Gallery" tab, users can choose multiple images and then have the ability to reorder images in a second page. When done, it inserts a shortcode such as: `[gallery ids="895,1007,986"]`

I would like to use this same interface so that users can select and reorder images. However, instead of returning a shortcode, I would like to return just a list of ID's of the images like so: `895,1007,986`

Another important thing is that my button will be in a metabox and the list of ID's will not be placed inside TinyMCE post edit area.

How can I achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `a = wp.media.gallery.edit('[gallery ids="2,1,3..."]');` like Wordpress does in media-editor.js.

I wasn't sure what event can catch the update, I found it with `a.on('all',function(n,a) {console.log(n); console.log(a)})`

Notice "update" in the log, and an object with a `models` array with the images. So, the quickest solutions using the gallery selector would be:

```
wp.media.gallery.edit('[gallery ids="numberlist"]').on('update',function(obj)
  { do something with obj.models)})
```

Comment: Awesome! Here is the code I used to get the numberlist:

`a = wp.media.gallery.edit('[gallery ids="2,1,3..."]').on('update',
function(obj) {
 var numberlist = [];
 $.each(obj.models, function(id,val) {numberlist.push(val.id)});
 do something with numberlist.join(",")
});`